# how to run "apport-collect 1311262" in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apport

I have file a bug in launchpad ubuntu. They asked me to run "apport-collect 1311262". I am unsure how to do this. Please help me do this. Thanks.

Comment: This is the link of the bug that i posted. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1311262

Answer (score 1):

Simply type `apport-collect 1311262` on the terminal. Apport will open your default browser and send you to the launchpad site where the bug was reported. You might need to install python-apport first, just in case so:

```
sudo apt-get install python-apport
```

`apport-collect` simply gathers needed information about your hardware, settings and more for that report (In this case 1311262) as seen by the number shown at the end of the URL:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1311262 <--- Number at the end is used with `apport-collect`.

This way apport knows where to send the gathered information.

For creating a non existing bug, `apport-bug` is used, similar to `ubuntu-bug`. For example in your case of having a compiz issue, you could do `ubuntu-bug compiz` or `apport-bug compiz` and that would gather the needed information in the first place.

For more information about bug reporting see [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug?lq=1)

Comment: How does this work on servers which only have CLI not GUI and without browsers?

Comment: @karthikvee You need to use for that particular case apport-cli which does not rely on GUI. apport-collect is just to add information to an existing bug report, while apport-cli is used to create a new bug report. They also offer the option of creating a file, then you would submit that file after you download it later to launchpad  (using a browser for example).